# i am having trouble renaming objects in my code but when i do it manually it works fine. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: bash, terminal

```
curl -# -O https://media.wix.com/ugd/d49749_7b2f263007bf4717ba5e6550a251f0d9.doc?dn=database.doc ; echo now uncrupting info... ; mv d49749_7b2f263007bf4717ba5e6550a251f0d9.doc?dn=database database.zip ; echo installing cart ; unzip database.zip ; say -i ok i finished it, thanks for waiting frend
```

i am trying to change d49749_7b2f263007bf4717ba5e6550a251f0d9.doc?dn=database to database.zip then unzip it but it keeps on saying

```
mv: rename database.zip to d49749_7b2f263007bf4717ba5e6550a251f0d9.doc?dn=database: No such file or directory
```

what am i doing wrong?
and i am sorry but i am still new to bash so i have **no** idea what i am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too see the name that it get's when it is downloaded I really think the name is *database.doc* and not *d49749_7b2f263007bf4717ba5e6550a251f0d9.doc?dn=database*

Or tell curl what name it should have once downloaded

Comment: how do i tell curl to do that?